# get objects of a file binarie

Tags: python, file

I can get all objects in the file.
here is error taht I had :

```
with open("Resultfill", "rb") as Resultfillread:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Resultfill'
```

Which means the file not exist. This has been resolved thanks to the answer just bellow.

But I always can't access the objects contained in file especialy with `yield`.
Here is objects contained in file binarie 'testfile'

```
di = {"c1": 3, "c2": 5, "c3": 13, "c4": 12, 5: 8, 6: 8, 7: 1, 8: 5, 9: 12, 10: 2, 11: 20, 12: 16, 13: 45, 14: 6, 15: 4 }
di = {1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 13, 4: 12, 5: 8, 6: 8, 7: 1, 8: 5, 9: 12, 10: 2, 11: 20, 12: 16, 13: 45, 14: 6, 15: 4 }
```

Here is code :

```
os.chdir("C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/testpython")
open("testfile", "ab")
def loadobject(fillname):
        with open(filename, "rb") as test:
            while True:
                 try:
                     yield pickle.load(test)
                 except EOFError:
                     break

genaratetest = loadobject("testfile")
print(Resultfillwrite)
for testobject in genaratetest:
     print(testobject)
```

I would that print(testobject) printed one object each loop turn, in this case here the first dictionary 'di' then the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're *writing* a new file, it will be created if it doesn't exist, but from `open("Resultfill", "rb")` you've said you want to *read* from the file. Creating a new file and then trying to read from it doesn't make much sense, so you get an error.

If there's a file which you're trying to read, please make sure the file exists and you're using the correct path.

If you're trying to create a new file or overwrite an existing one, use `open("Resultfill", "wb")`

You can see the documentation on [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for subtleties and other options.

Comment: Thanks, I create the file and no more error on this point. But I can't access the objects of file. While the objects have to be accessible by `yield`, that I may be using incorrectly. Of this that I get it, `yield` return a generator who can be placed in a interator for genarate the object on the fly. We doing as I did, I should get the items but this does not works. Can you explain why ? I evolved my question

Comment: Make sure you call `pickle.load(test)`  _only_ _once_ per file. You want the `yield` inside the loop, but the `load()` should be outside it.